# How do divide into another column using a mysql trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am fairly new to MySQL and I have been stumped by this problem for a bit. This is what I have so far but it doesn't work.

```
create trigger CalculateAvgACD after insert on agent
    for each row begin
        update agent set AvgACDTime=new.AnsweredCalls/new.TotalACDTime
        where TotalACDTime != -1;
    end;
```

A friend of mine told me that MySQL has some quirks in it's syntax that I should ask about. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks all

Comment: You cannot update table 'agent', because trigger 'CalculateAvgACD' is associated with this table.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a `update`, `insert` or `delete` statement in a trigger on the same table.

You need to manipulate the `NEW` virtual table instead.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER CalculateAvgACD AFTER INSERT ON agent FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (NEW.TotalACDTime != -1) AND (NEW.TotalACDTime <> 0) THEN
    SET NEW.AvgACDTime = NEW.AnsweredCalls/NEW.TotalACDTime;
  END IF;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

This code does the same thing as your code, but because it only works with the NEW values in the current row it will work without MySQL complaining about the trigger being self-referential.
Note that I also fixed a potential `divide by zero` error.